# Pandas remove all single characters from dataframe

Tags: pandas

How to use pandas replace (or any other function) to remove all single characters in a dataframe so that:

```
abc   87-2    EF.2  
ABC      a       -
EF8      8  
.        B
```

Becomes:

```
 abc  87-2    EF.2  
 ABC            
 EF8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First if necessary select only strings columns (obviously `object`s are strings), get length and set empty value by `mask`:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(object).columns

df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df.applymap(len) == 1, '')
print (df)
   abc 87-2 EF.2
0  ABC          
1  EF8          
2
```

If need replace values also in substrings:

```
f = lambda x: ' '.join(y for y in x.split() if len(y) != 1)
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(f)
```